# Android drag-n-drop from app to app

Tags: android, mobile, drag-and-drop, mobile-application, samsung-mobile

In Windows it is possible to drag-n-drop from application to application using [OLE drag-n-drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Is this possible with the new multi-windowed flavors of Android?

Comment: At the moment, there is only one "multi-windowed flavor of Android", which is the Samsung series with S-Apps. You can check the S-Pen SDK to see if they offer something like this, if you can stomach the SDK license agreement (icky the last time I looked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot drag from one app and drop on another.